# Applying \LARGE\rmfamily\scshape\textbf to entire title in beamer class

Tags: beamer, fonts, titles, fontsize

I'm trying to apply `\LARGE\rmfamily\scshape\textbf` to an entire title and `\rmfamily\scshape\textbf` to an entire subtitle in the beamer class (see the minimal working example below). However, if I use `{\LARGE\rmfamily\scshape\textbf some title}`, only the first letter is bold (see the picture below). If I apply `\LARGE\rmfamily\scshape\textbf{some subtitle}`, only the last command gets applied, which is `textbf` or equivalently `bfseries` (see the picture below). This issue also appears in the comment and answer given below.

My question is: how can I apply *all* the commands, not only the bold one? In other words, how can I make the entire title `\LARGE`, `\rmfamily`, `\scshape`, `\textbf`, and the entire subtitle `\rmfamily`, `\scshape`, `\textbf`?

Thanks for your help!

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=blue,bg=blue!10}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=blue,bg=blue!10}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

\setbeamersize{text margin left=4em, text margin right=4em}
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\large}
\title[]{\LARGE\rmfamily\scshape\textbf some title}
\subtitle{\rmfamily\scshape\textbf{some subtitle}}
\author[]{}
\institute[]{}
\date[]{}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\begin{center}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\bfseries` not `\textbf` as the latter requires an argument whereas `\bfseries` does not. Also note that you will need a font that supports bold small case letters, not all fonts do.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! If I use `\bfseries`, then `\LARGE\rmfamily\scshape` will be ignored. This is the issue that I mentioned above: if I apply `\LARGE\rmfamily\scshape\textbf{some subtitle}` (or equivalently `\bfseries` instead of `\textbf`), only the last command gets applied -- the (sub)title gets bold but nothing else happens. The question is: how can I apply *all* the commands, not only the bold one?

Comment: It will also be ignored with `\textbf` see the log there is most likely no available font combination for rm+sc+bf, see your image none are bold small caps.

Answer (score 2):

Not all font support bold and small caps. Try this.

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{libertine} % added font

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=blue,bg=blue!10}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=blue,bg=blue!10}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

\setbeamersize{text margin left=4em, text margin right=4em}
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\large}
%\title[]{\LARGE\rmfamily\scshape\textbf some title}
\title[]{\Huge\sffamily\scshape\textbf{Some Title}}
\subtitle{\rmfamily\scshape\textbf{some subtitle}}
\author[]{}
\institute[]{}
\date[]{}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{frame}
    \titlepage
    \begin{center}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: outb]

Now comment the line `\usepackage{libertine}` and compile again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My problem is that `\LARGE\rmfamily\scshape` will be ignored if I follow your advice. This is the issue that I mentioned above: if I apply `\LARGE\rmfamily\scshape\textbf{some (sub)title}`, only the last command gets applied -- the (sub)title gets bold but nothing else happens. The question is: how can I apply *all* the commands, not only the bold one?

Comment: @Thomas They were applied. See the updated answer.  Not all fonts support small caps and bold face.

Answer (score 0):

The Computer Modern and Latin Modern fonts don't offer the bold/serif/scshape combination of font dimensions. The `\rmfamily\bfseries` and `\rmfamily\scshape` combinations are available, but `\rmfamily\scshape\bfseries` is not.

If using the `\rmfamily\scshape\bfseries` combination is critical to you, you need to switch to a font family that provides this combination. Times (New) Roman is one such font family. Try running `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` before `\title{\LARGE\rmfamily\bfseries\scshape Some Title}`.

Comment: Why did somebody downvote this answer? Please enlighten me.

Comment: Well.. it motivated me to amplify.